# Application of Fourier series, uniformly convergence

Tags: analysis

A useful type of series of functions is Fourier series. Let (ak)∞k=0 and (bk)∞k=0, and let gk(x)=akcos(2πkx)+bksin(2πkx).

A natural questions is: for what sequences (ak), (bk) does the Fourier series ∑k=0∞gk converge uniformly.

How do you prove that if ∑|ak| and ∑|bk| both converge, then the Fourier series ∑k=0∞gk converges uniformly to a function f.

In this case can you find a formula for ak, bk?

Comment: You need to use latex symbols to make it look better!

Answer (score 0):

Is a trivial consequence of [Weierstrass M-test:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test)
$$|a_k\cos(2k\pi x)+b_k\sin(2k\pi x)|\le|a_k\cos(2k\pi x)|+|b_k\sin(2k\pi x)|\le|a_k|+|b_k|.$$

Comment: I see how you use the triangle inequality to get to |ak|+|bk|but how can you prove that |ak|+|bk|≤ Mk? I am assuming that is how you apply the Weierstrass M-test.

Comment: @Rae, $\sum(|a_k|+|b_k|)=\sum|a_k|+\sum|b_k|$.